# tensorflow mnist (change image size)

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I've been studying with the Tensorflow library doing the MNIST tutorials.
Now I wanted to study with my own data. (Image size 28x28 -> 188x188 and 3 Classes).

but I don't know how to calculate the weight(shape parameter?).

I know.. 28*28 = 784 -> 188*188 = 35344.. That's it.
Help me!

[Code modify]

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 35344])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([35344,3]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,188,188,1])
#x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# Second layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Densely Connected Layer

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# Dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# Readout layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 3])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([3])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

# Train and Evaluate the Model

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(2000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(35)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

[Error Message]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class3.py", line 253, in <module>
    x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 555, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3498, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 4948160 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 3136
     [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MaxPool_1, Reshape_1/shape)]]
Caused by op u'Reshape_1', defined at:
  File "class3.py", line 229, in <module>
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1383, in reshape
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Answer (score 0):

from the code given above i found some mistakes:

if you want to study your own dataset of images 188x188, you'll need to feed it images from your dataset instead of doing batch = mnist.train.next_batch(35)

you'll want to read some of the examples on the tensorflow website here to understand how you can read data into the graph
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html

also the x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 188, 188, 1]) might not be required depending on how you read the data. each image the preprocessed mnist dataset on the tensorflow.examples is of the shape (784,), which is why we needed to reshape it with (-1,28,28,1) this converts the tensor of shape (784,) to a 2d image 28x28 with 1 channel